# Should unique string part of an invite-link be encrypted?

Tags: encryption

Consider an invite link like this: `https://mysite.com/invite-link/{uniquestring}`
The `uniquestring` part of the URL is the part with which server-side application can lookup the invitation information from the database(so in a way it serves as invitation ID).
Aside from the fact that the endpoint that is responsible for handling invite links will be properly rate limited.
If I use `uuidv4` as `uniquestring`, would the following actions be necessary?

1. encrypt `uniquestring`(symmetric encryption) and put the encrypted `unqiuestirng` in invite-link `https://mysite.com/invite-link/{encrypted_uniquestring}` and send it to user in email/SMS(`uniquestring` itself will be saved to the database, not the encrypted version of it)
2. In the endpoint responsible for registration through invite link: decrypt `encrypted_uniquestring`(sent in request body) and search the database for an invitation using `uniquestring`

It seems to me that this method makes it harder for attackers to guess invite-links since they have to pass the encryption as well. Is this correct? Would it be necessary? Is it a common practice for invite-link creation?

Comment: Is the invite ID a sequential number? You mentioned UUIDv4 which is a 128-bit random value. What additional value of encryption over a random number do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the `uniquestring` is a token that represents an invitation id. *Assuming that it's produced randomly* (you mention using UUIDs), the contents of a token convey no meaning. As such, a token's significance relies on its uniqueness and unpredictability (you cannot guess valid new tokens), not its content - which makes encryption pretty much useless in this case (encryption is *basically* used to provide confidentiality).

So your biggest issue is to make sure that the unique string does not fall to the wrong hands. Encryption does not help here because if an attacker is able to steal an unencrypted token, then he'll be able to also steal an encrypted one; then he can just use that and the result will be the same as using an unencrypted token.

> If I use uuidv4 as uniquestring, would the following actions be necessary?

No.

> It seems to me that this method makes it harder for attackers to guess invite-links since they have to pass the encryption as well. Is this correct?

No, any attacker will find it difficult to guess any (pseudo) random sequence of bits. Encryption does not add anything valuable in this process - see above.

> Would it be necessary? Is it a common practice for invite-link creation?

No and no. UUIDs are perfectly fine for this, or any other randomly generated unique token. Just make sure that the token does not fall to the wrong hands (maybe introduce authentication in the process?)